# How to write multiple rewrite conditions and rules in one .htaccess file for redirecting urls?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have sub-site named `subsite.site.com` (just and example). firstly i want to redirect `subsite.site.com` to `www.subsite.site.com`and and finally i want to redirect `www.subsite.site.com` to `www.subsite.site.com/directory/subdirectory/index.html`

the following rewrite conditions & rules serve this purpose independently.

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite.site\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subsite.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subsite\.site\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.subsite\.site\.com\/directory\/subdirectory\/" [R=301,L
```

how shall i combine the above two conditions & rules in a single `.htaccess` file?

thanks,

Answer (score 6):

> how shall i combine the above two conditions & rules in a single .htaccess file?

Just put one after the other in the same file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subsite\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /directory/subdirectory/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite.site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subsite.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with a single redirect to the browser? So Apache can process all rules and send a Location header to the end result, but to work even if one of the rules doesn't match. Thanks!