# Handling multiple re-writing and redirection with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Working with .htaccess has always been little confusing for many developers.

Currently I am also experiencing a issue

we want 3-4 things to work simultaneously with htaccess

1) redirect non-www to www

2) remove .php extension

3) for pages with trailing parameters abc.php?pageid=28 and abc.php?pageid=95&cat=92 - these pages must show their actual page names like www.xyz.com/about-us rather than ids.

all above must work together.

Comment: Kindly show us what you have tried, also `php != .htaccess` remove the php tag.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following links, it may resolve the issues.

[How to write multiple rewrite conditions and rules in one .htaccess file for redirecting urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501235/how-to-write-multiple-rewrite-conditions-and-rules-in-one-htaccess-file-for-red?rq=1)

[htaccess mod_rewrite - Trailing Slash and loop of redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602310/htaccess-mod-rewrite-trailing-slash-and-loop-of-redirects?rq=1)

[.htaccess - Rewrite multiple subdirectories to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103669/htaccess-rewrite-multiple-subdirectories-to-root?rq=1)